# What's new with the 12.0 preview version

Tags: general-utilities

Lately, Mathematica 12.0 preview has been released. However unable to get a copy, I'm curious to know the new features of that version

Comment: You can check Wolfram's YouTube channel with presentations from WTC2018. Otherwise it is a question to WRI because mortal beta testers are not allowed to talk too much before release.

Comment: As Kuba said, beta testers were explicitly asked not to discuss the prerelease in public.  Thus voting to close.

Comment: Can someone outline the benefit of even having this information at this point in time, outside of satisfying some curiosity?

Comment: @user6014 Considering the amount of "live CEOing" videos by Mr. Wolfram it's a bit hard to see the point. Surely there are details they prefer to talk less openly, but lots of if is largely out in the open - at least if you care to watch hundreds of hours of planning meeting recordings.

Comment: The only feature I’m truly enthusiastic about is the transition to 64bit front end for the mac.  I remember a talk by one of the developers mentioning a noticeable speed up, and less crashes.

Comment: As the [what's-new page](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/cloudplatform/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn120.html) is out, would it be appropriate to continue this discussion?